# Pandas division by zero, errors despite np.where condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I am using jupyter notebooks and I have a function that uses the

```
data['woe2'] = np.log(data['B']/data['MonthSales'])
```

equation. The issue i'm having is that when 'B' equals 0 Python throws a tantrum over division by 0. This happens even though I tried using np.where to make an exception. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["John","Deep","Julia","Kate","Sandy"], 
                     "MonthSales" : [25,30,35,40,45], "B" : [10,0,0,20,40]})
data['woe2'] = np.where((data['B'] != 0),
                               np.log(data['B']/data['MonthSales']), 0)
```

Comment: `np.where` is a NOT a conditional evaluator.  It's a conditional selector.  More details in this recent SO (about `np.log` as well), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75443369/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log-in-numpy-log-even-though-sma. `np.log(data['B']/data['MonthSales'])` is evaluated for every row of the dataframe, and then passed to `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't complaining about division BY zero, but division of zero by a non-zero denominator.  It is producing `-inf`.

Here is a bit cleaner way to do it, as you can pass Pandas tests in as conditionals.

> data_bool = data['B'] != 0
>
> data['woe2'] = np.log(data[data_bool]['B']/data[data_bool]['MonthSales'])

Comment: And then I have to get rid of NaN values?     I guess a single line solution cannot really be obtained then? The below throws in errors understandably                                                        
data['woe2'] = np.where((data['B'] != 0),
                               np.log(data[data_bool]['B']/data[data_bool]['MonthSales']), 0)

Comment: You can 'fix' it with `df.fillna(0)` but sums and other operations should just skip over NAs.  As missing values is data, setting them to `0` can be like manufacturing data so is context specific.

Comment: The virtues of one-liners in python can be overblown.  In a previous SO I showed that `np.log` takes a `where` parameter, but looking carefully at the division warning, it's `pandas.core.arraylike` that's complaining, not `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

In recent:

["RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log" in numpy.log even though small values were filtered out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75443369/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log-in-numpy-log-even-though-sma)

we explain that `np.where` is a conditional selector; its arguments are evaluated in full first.

The Series division:

```
In [72]: data['B']/data['MonthSales']                                                                                   
Out[72]:                                                                                                                
0    0.400000                                                                                                           
1    0.000000                                                                                                           
2    0.000000                                                                                                           
3    0.500000                                                                                                           
4    0.888889                                                                                                           
 dtype: float64
```

Taking the `log`, raises the warning.  Note it is issued by `pandas.core.arraylike`:

```
In [73]: np.log(data['B']/data['MonthSales'])                                                                           
C:\Users\paul\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:402: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log                                                                                                                        
result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)                                                                    
Out[73]:                                                                                                                
0   -0.916291                                                                                                           
1        -inf                                                                                                           
2        -inf                                                                                                           
3   -0.693147                                                                                                           
4   -0.117783                                                                                                            
 dtype: float64
```

If instead we take the log of the equivalent array, using the `where/out` parameters to make it conditional, we avoid the warning:

```
In [74]: np.log((data['B']/data['MonthSales']).values, where=data['B']>0, 
out=np.zeros(data.shape[0]))                  
Out[74]: array([-0.91629073,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.69314718, -0.11778304])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that warning is just not significant (like all warnings), indeed, in [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html), they put an example with 0 in the argument array and when we run the same code of the example, it goes with the same warning